# SQL (PostgreSQL): How to write a query to get a list of names with same last names from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of the list of actors. Now what I want to have is a list of the actors who have the same surnames. If an actor has a unique surname, he won't show up in the result set.

For this, I tried:

```
SELECT a1.first_name, a1.last_name 
FROM actor a1, actor a2 
WHERE a1.last_name = a2.last_name AND a1.actor_id !=  a2.actor_id
ORDER BY a1.last_name;
```

Now it works fine, except for I am getting multiple duplicate entries. Like in the picture attached here.

Result with duplicate entries.

[image: Result with duplicate entries.]

Of course, it is obvious that every time an entry matches with last_name of another entry, an actor's name is printed on the list. If it matches with two other people, it prints it out two times. But the desired way is to print just once even in there are many other matches, like in the picture here.

Desired result:

[image: Desired result.]

Comment: Showing sample data as screenshots is not a really a good [idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)  as it makes it nearly impossible to use the sample data to test the query (no copy & paste possible). For future questions please add [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I've taken a note of that. Will do the same from next time I post a problem. Thank you for helping me btw! :) Your solution works with obvious modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a join, use an co-related sub query with EXISTS instead:

```
select a1.*
from actor a1
where exists (select *
              from actor a2
              where a2.last_name = a1.last_name
                and a2.actor_id <> a1.actor_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, just add a `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT a1.first_name, a1.last_name 
FROM actor a1, actor a2 
WHERE a1.last_name = a2.last_name AND a1.actor_id !=  a2.actor_id
GROUP BY a1.first_name, a1.last_name
ORDER BY a1.last_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Your solution works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the DISTINCT clause which is used in the SELECT statement to remove duplicate rows from the result set.

Please this article: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

So your query would look like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT a1.first_name, a1.last_name 
FROM actor a1, actor a2 
WHERE a1.last_name = a2.last_name AND a1.actor_id !=  a2.actor_id
ORDER BY a1.last_name;`